# Solving the recurrence T(n) = T(n/2) + T(2n/3) + O(n)?

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

Is O(nlogn) accurate for this recurrence, I tried testing T(n)/O(nlogn) and it seems that the ratio is not much constant. Just hope a detailed mathematic proof of this recurrence.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a mathematics question, not a programming question.

Comment: It's not. Try [Akra--Bazzi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method).